# DataFrame manipulation which dataframe do not have numeric value to aggretate

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Basiclly, I have dataframe as below

[image: img]

I would like to transform my table above and resulting as below
whereby the [?] need to lookup values from column [ColumnD]

I have tried Pandas.GroupBy and Pandas.Pivot, those give me no LUCK. Pandas.Pivot require numeric value in values field, while pandas.groupby is kind of messy procedure

Any one can suggest clean and fast method to get result as in second table

appreciate :)

Comment: It would help if you included runnable code and data in your question. Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A copy-pasteable text table is much preferred to an image.

Comment: From figure above, consider left side of table as dataframe while right is the result I need...when I issue pandas.pivot_table(df, rows=['Column_A','Column_b'],cols='column_c', values='Column_D').. It pop me no numeric for aggregate

Comment: Any method can use in python so that my result appear as right side of table in figure... I would also need to lookup value in column and rows, how to perform that.. It will be same like index..match in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The method you are looking for is [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = \
"""Column_A;Column_B;Column_C;Column_D
12L; ITEM_a;  DEF;     12 (L1,L3)
12L; ITEM_B; DEF;      13 (L1,L3)
12L; ITEM_a; DEF;      14 (L1,L3)
12L; ITEM_N; DEF;      15 (L1,L3)
12L; ITEM_I; DEF;      16 (L1,L3)
12L; ITEM_P; SIDE_X;   17 (L1,L3)
8L;  ITEM_P; SIDE_x;   13 (L1,L3)
7L;  ITEM_A; SIDE_x;   19 (L1,L3)
1L;  ITEM_Q; SIDE_Y;   20 (L1,L3)
4L;  ITEM_I; SIDE_X;   21 (L1,L3)
4L;  ITEM_A; SIDEJ;    22 (L1,L3)
4L;  ITEMB;  SIDEJ;    23 (L1,L3)
4L;  ITEM_B; SIDE_X;   24 (L1,L3)
2L;  ITEM_A; SIDE_x;   25 (L1,L3)
3L;  Z;      SD_U;     26 (L1,L3)
8L;  XC;     AS;       27 (L1,L3)"""

# Creation of the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep = ';', index_col = [0,1,2])
# Perform the magic operation (unstack) on the dataframe
df = df.unstack(level=-1)
# Remove the first multilevel index in the columns
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
# Remove spaces contained in columns
df.columns = [i.strip() for i in df.columns.values]
print df
```

Comment: the [df.columns.droplevel(0)] is doing merging process??

Comment: Hi,

another challenge raise this time, refer link below for my document

[sample][1]

FYI, the document is a xls file, there are 2 sheets inside, which named as raw_data & result_page

provided raw_data in file, did you guys found any method using python, pandas to have a similar output as in result_page sheet

aprreatiate your help, I am frustrated about this few days


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3MXf_9RtXI-dUVySUpaZGxaNW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to group columns with command grouby and also to play with command stack and unstack.